# Image load with site load

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Hello I make simple [site](http://bhpcontrol.pl) but I have a little trouble with loading images. As you can see with new category there is new image. There is a problem, beacause only then img is loading, and I want to load all images when my site is loading.
sample code how I operate with those img.

```
imgUrls.push("img/01.jpg");
imgUrls.push("img/02.jpg");
var k3:Boolean=false;

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvet.CLICK, clickFunc);
function clickFunc(e:MouseEvent):void
if (k3==false)
{
    img1.myUILoader.source = imgUrls[0];
    k3=true;

}else
{
    img2.myUILoader.source = imgUrls[0];
    k3=false;
}

btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvet.CLICK, clickFunc2);
function clickFunc2(e:MouseEvent):void
if (k3==false)
{
    img1.myUILoader.source = imgUrls[1];
    k3=true;

}else
{
    img2.myUILoader.source = imgUrls[1];
    k3=false;
}
```

So my question is: **How can I load all img with site.?**

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate post of the two other questions you just asked.  Please combine them into one question, adding to it as you discover more of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently is telling the program to load the images when either `btn1` or `btn2` is clicked. You need to tell the program to load the images right away, before user input, then have `btn1` and `btn2` display them.

Comment: Ok but how can I tell him that?

Comment: Well, if `img1.myUILoader.source = imgUrls[0];` tells it to load, put it right after `imgUrls.push("img/01.jpg");`

Comment: yea but as you can see at site I always use img1.myUILoader and img2.myUILoader.