# One Loader appears in two MC

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

according to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701202/image-load-with-site-load) (I suggest read it for full understand this question) I've concluded that I have to use several Loaders. At first I was thinking "oh well I just use sixteen loaders", but do I have to? Maybe I should  create only eigth of them? Then I found this [tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/).

If I'm correct I just have to create eight Loaders, then addChild to correct img1/img2?

What you think guys? I'll be thankful for answer.

Comment: Regarding "One Loader appears in two MC" - a Loader is a DisplayObject and can only appear at one place in the display list at a time. You cannot display a Loader in two places, in two MC's, at the same time. So you will need at least as many Loaders as images that you want to display at the same time. Beyond that, I think it is hard to tell from your question(s) how many Loaders you would need.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate post of the two other questions you just asked.  Please combine them into one question, adding to it as you discover more of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need one loader, but that depends on how many things you want downloading at once.  8 loaders will have (potentially) 8 images being sent at once (this may be limited by the server, of course).  You would assign all the images to one array, then loop on that array where needed.  If you want 8 images loading, then (using the code in the linked example) it would be something like:

```
import mx.controls.Loader;

var imgArr:Array = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg",/* and so on */,"imgN.jpg" ];
var ldrArr:Array = [];

for (var :Number = 0;  < imgArr.length; ++) 
{
    ldrArr[i] = new Loader();
    ldrArr[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);
    ldrArr[i].load(new URLRequest(imgArr[i]));
}

function finishLoading(e:Event):void {
    // Get the current loader
    var curLdr:Loader = (e.target as Loader);
    curLdr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);

    addChild(curLdr); // you will have to fix this to actually load the image
}
```

But if you want only one loader, try this:

```
import mx.controls.Loader;

var imgArr:Array = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg",/* and so on */,"imgN.jpg" ];
var ldr:Loader;

function startLoader() {
    if ( imgArr.length > 0 )
    {
        ldr = new Loader();
        ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);
        ldr.load(new URLRequest(imgArr.pop());
    }
}

function finishLoading(e:Event):void {
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);

    addChild(ldr); // you will have to fix this to actually load the image

    // start over with next image:
    startLoader();
}
```

Comment: You starting intresting problem with loading content. I already [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771952/loading-loader-content-with-stage) question about it. If you may read it :)

And I use one loader with adding and removing children

Comment: I really do not understand what you are asking, then.  This method will work -- why are you asking so many questions for the same problem?  What is the difference between this question and the one you link to?

Comment: No, there I ask about synchronising loading loader content and stage in one preloader, here I ask about using this loaders in mc.

Comment: These questions are very similar.  I understand that there may be a language barrier, but loading an image to the stage, to an MC, to some random container, multiple loaders, loaders in series, reusing loaders, and so on . . . they are all problems looking for a general solution.  Maybe try searching for a loading class, and just use that when needed.  But because these answers will be so similar, you should be able to answer other questions for yourself, *if* you work on the concepts many people here have presented.